# How to get Near Location in Mongoose Aggregation Operators using $geoNear, $lookup and $match?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Can u help me to fix this, i try to search near location using namaKota(City Name) and Lat,Long for Parameter. here my code

```
 var namaKota = "Malang";
 var coords = [];
    coords[0] =lat;
    coords[1] =long;

 VehiclesDB.aggregate([
            {
                $geoNear: {
                    geoNear: "rentaldbs",
                    near: coords,
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup:
                    {
                        from: "rentaldbs",
                        localField: "mitraId",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "mitra"
                    }}
            ,
            {
                $unwind: "$mitra"
            },{

                $match: {
                    "mitra.namaKota": namaKota
                }
            }
```

And My Result Like this

```
Couldn't find any Vehicles with idMalang
```

Comment: I am new to $geoNear. When I looked on the documentation , I couldn't find any option of geoNear in it. Please check it. It's options include, spherical, limit, num, maxDistance, query, distanceMultiplier, uniqueDocs, near, distanceField, includeLocs, and minDistance. Please check it.

Comment: here documentations about geoNear https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/